# How can I make the loop to count the gene against query id

Tags: r, loops

I have the data frame in R with 14 columns and 4.4 million rows.

column 1 has the query id and  column 4 has the gene name.

I want to make the data frame that can show which and how many genes corresponding to each query id.

I have 44K  different query ids and each query have maximum ~100 genes hit

```
CSAI_contig04661_6  sp  O65396  GCST    ARATH   86.03   408 56  1   72  478 1   408 0.0e+00 738.0
CSAI_contig04661_6  sp  Q681Y3  Y1099   ARATH   22.55   337 244 10  140 474 103 424 8.0e-09 56.6
CSAI_contig04661_6  sp  Q9FLR5  SMC6A   ARATH   24.27   103 66  3   04. Jun 249 342 441 4.6e+00 28. Sep
CSAI_contig04661_6  sp  Q9LQI7  GCST    ARATH   24.28   74  47  2   17. Aug 300 31  100 8.1e+00 27. Jul
CSAI_contig04661_6  sp  P56795  RK22    ARATH   28.95   76  49  4   11. Mrz 509 15  87  8.4e+00 27. Mrz
CSAI_isotig00001_4  sp  Q8VZE4  PP299   ARATH   29.63   108 55  5   31. Jul 307 10  109 1.6e+00 30. Apr
```

I am interested in this type of output.

```
 CSAI_contig04661_6     
 GCST       2    
 Y1099      1     
 SMC6A      1     
 RK22       1
```

How can I make a loop that check column 1 until they have same query (for example in this example it has 6 ) and then go to the column 4 and find how many genes are present and count their number if more than one (in this example against first query GCST is present 2 times)

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this easily with [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html):

```
group_by(df, V1, V4) %>% 
    summarise(n=n()) %>% 
    group_by(V1) %>% 
    summarise(hits=paste(paste(V4, n), collapse=" "))
```

Comment: I think it will just give me the frequency of the genes regardless of the query id. But the problem is as in this example I have 5 genes against 1st query id (in other words first query has 5 different gene hits) and I want the output as I mentioned in the question first is the query id and then is the genes and their frequency.

Comment: What do you get when you try his code? I can't read in your data (directly).

Comment: This will group by query_id, then by gene and give the frequency of each gene for each query. That's what you want, no? The output looks just like your example: `1 CSAI_contig04661_6  GCST   2,  2 CSAI_contig04661_6  RK22   1,  3 CSAI_contig04661_6 SMC6A   1,   4 CSAI_contig04661_6 Y1099   1,  5 CSAI_isotig00001_4 PP299   1`

Comment: Yes, It's the same thing what I need but a little bit modification I still need in this output. I wanted to print the query only against all the genes of that query. For example`CSAI_contig04661_6`   only once instead of 4 times.

Comment: ` 1 CSAI_contig04661_6 GCST 2, RK22 1,  SMC6A 1,  Y1099 1,                   2 CSAI_isotig00001_4 PP299 1`

Comment: I've edited the answer to give all of the hits on one line. I hope it works. I didn't test it because I'm too lazy to edit your screwy tab delimited data again